# I can't vote but can accept on low quality review

Tags: support, bug, review, accepted-answer, low-quality-posts

While I cannot vote when reviewing a low quality post, it *is* possible to accept it (when it is an answer to your own question). I don't think that's meant this way?

[image]

Comment: What is the problem here? It's an answer to your own question. Why should you not be able to accept it, even when it shows up in a review queue?

Comment: @Bart there was a reason to remove the vote buttons, I suppose. That reason probably also applies on the accept button, but I'm not sure because I don't know the reason for removing the vote buttons.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely clear on that either. Though I assume it's to not let votes count as a review action which might result in some crazy upvoting. While accepting is an action only you can take and is perfectly fine if it's an actual correct/helpful answer to your question.

Comment: @Bart you got a point on that, I added [meta-tag:support] to the tags.

Comment: Going by [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191294/201409) one of the reasons there are not voting buttons is that you're not viewing the answer in the context of the other answers. I think that's even *more* reason to also not show the accept button. I'd definitely support removing the button there.