# Why is there no ability to Vote when reviewing a Low Quality Post?

Tags: feature-request, review, voting, low-quality-posts

In my time reviewing, I have noticed several Low Quality Posts which have been automatically flagged as such, and while "Looks Good" is a fine button to select, some of these posts warrant a vote (up, usually; sometimes down, but not deletion), yet this option doesn't exist on the page, when it does exist for other items being reviewed (First Posts, Late Answers).

Certainly, I "get" that at this point the reviewer is considered an experienced 2k user and can be trusted to click into the post and vote it external to reviewing, but I don't see why the extra clicks are necessary; throw us a bone here and put the voting arrows in, or explain the rationale behind the decision to not include them.

Though I realize (unlike First Posts and Late Answers) we aren't locked on the review page, if the rationale to not including vote buttons is that reviewers will simply vote then click done, consider a voting action to be optional and require a non-vote action to conclude the review.

Comment: And in the case where it *is* low-quality, I've been skipping them in the review queue and voting separately out of concern that review data might be used to train the auto-flagger.  IAW, I don't click "looks good" unless it does.  But now I wonder if this is a factor.

Comment: related: [I can't vote but can accept on low quality review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176367/165773)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system, and my related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143703/allow-more-actions-from-review

Comment: Ok, so based on @bfavaretto 's link, the rationale behind not having the voting buttons on the Low Quality Posts queue is that we are not viewing the post in context of the question and therefore are not in the capacity to be able to judge the post (vote-wise) positively or negatively, and we are expected to enter the "prominently linked" question and vote on it.  Wouldn't having the referential question available to the LQP review (same as the FP and LA reviews) then make sense so the reviewer can judge if the LQ flag (and subsequently VOTING) is warranted?

Comment: I cannot recall offhand (and I'm not waiting for another one to be added to the queues to go look at it) if we already do have "preview" access to view the original question (like FPs and LAs) to place the LQP being reviewed in context, but if we don't, we SHOULD and if we DO, we should have voting buttons.